# How can I create a view in MVC that allows me to add multiple new child entities to a new parent entity using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have an object ItemA and it has a list of objects ItemB (a one to many relationship):

```
public class ItemA {
    public List<ItemB> virtual ListOfB { get; set; }
    ...properties...
}

public class ItemB {
    public ItemA ItemA { get; set; }
    ...properties...
}
```

What is a clean way in the **create** view for class A to make it so I can add multiple new instances of B to A all at the same time? Specifically, is EF smart enough to know to "package up" all of the form data submitted for the B's and put them into the list for A and then save it all?

Answer (score 0):

You can add ItemA id as a foreign key in the ItemB Class

```
ItemB
{

int Id{get;set;}
int ItemA_Id{get;set;}

[ForeignKey("ItemA_Id")]
public virtual IteamA ItemA {get; set;}
}
```

and in your ItemA Class you can add ItemB as a Collection

```
ItemA
{

int Id{get;set;}

public virtual ICollection<IteamB> ItemBs {get; set;}
}
```